# How to tunnel intranet web site with php file?

Tags: php, internet, intranet

I have this configuration:

```
                   ________
                  |        |
Internet ----->   | Server |  ----> All intranet server
       port(443)  |        | 
       port(80)    --------
```

So I can put a php code and run command line. Then, I can access any intranet website with a `curl` command. But a website is complex and you will need to download javascript, images, etc..

Is there a way to do a "Browser in Browser" or the best, can I tunnel this connection with a php code? So, I request a page in the browser, like `192.168.0.1` and it translate to this "tunnel", make the request and show the result in my browser?

How can I access the intranet site only with  ports `80` and/or `443`?

Comment: why do you need another server in the chain?  Intranet is local... what is it you are trying to accomplish?  Are you trying to map a local IP to the internet, and then back to the intranet?

Comment: This is a pentest scenary. If you have a kind of web backdoor, can you access the intranet web sites? You can with curl, but command line navegation is dificult.

Comment: If the attacker can install and execute programs, they'd have a number of choices.  Selenium or JavaFX come to mind.  (assuming the web server can access the intranet...)  You might still need to provide credentials.  (if the intranet is secure)

Comment: @pcalkins `Selenium automates browsers`.. This is a new idea for me. It is very close to the answer. Is there a way to "remote controll" the browser in the server? Yes, there is: Selenium RC

Comment: Selenium is designed for testing, so it does just that... automates the browser.  You can also use HTMLUnit with Selenium which is it's own "silent" browser and webdriver in one.  That would make it a little easier on an attacker, since they would only need to execute a JAR file.

Comment: @pcalkins.. Humm.. Do you know some project? This is still command line. Think like this: I open the browser in the server and it access the site. It print the result and send me the image. Then, I say click link in x possition. It click and send the image result. So, it "tunnel" the connection and every thing can be done by port 80/443.

Comment: Selenium Grid would allow you to remotely launch drivers/browsers.